# C# .NET Core 2.2 Web-Api 500 only on Kestrel only one endpoint

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, kestrel

I got a Web-Api project. This project is rolled out on a kestrel as a service.
Now one of all my endpoints returns straight a 500, the others work fine. And the 500 I get only on kestrel, also while using kestrel local for debugging.

I empty my controller (code inside the controller class), simplified like code below. I tried changing the name. This all makes no difference. And the controller looks the same than other controller classes.

I know, it is a hard question, but where could I look for the solution of this problem that I get always a 500 response straight away?

Frank

```
namespace DataPicker.Api.Controllers
{
  [Produces("application/json")]
  [Route("api/v1/dataPicker/environmentData")]
  public class TimeSeriesController : Controller
  {
    public TimeSeriesController(){}

    [HttpPost()]
    public async Task<IActionResult> 
    CreateAsync([FromBody]Data data)
    {
        return Ok("received");
    }

    public class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("text", Required = Required.AllowNull)]
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
  }
}
```

Curl:
curl -X POST "http://localhost:5000/api/v1/dataPicker/environmentData" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"text\": \"string\"}"

Response:
500, Error: Internal Server Error
Response headers
 content-length: 0 
 date: Mon, 17 Jun 2019 16:18:24 GMT 
 server: Kestrel

Comment: look at the logging.

Comment: @DanielA.White the log is written, when I start the API, but still other Endpoints work fine:
2019-06-17 18:20:46.1100||WARN|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Overriding address(es) 'http://localhost:59883/'. Binding to endpoints defined in UseKestrel() instead. |url: |action:

Comment: what exception is thrown on that endpoint that fails?

Comment: Have you tried putting an explicit route on your action and calling that?

Comment: @DanielA.White The breakpoint inside the controller or its constructor is never reached. Before I get the message 500 Error: Internal Server Error

Comment: So yea look thru your logs for exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the solution fits to the problem but I got it working through  setting the url's in a different way than before:

launchSettings.json:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "commandName": "Project",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  },
  "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000/"
}
```

Programm.cs:

```
        public static IWebHostBuilder BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000")
            .UseKestrel();
```